# Why do I have to add boilerplate to make Codable work even if I only have one element I need to customize?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

I'm using `Codable` in Swift, and it's cool that for super simple models I don't have to implement any custom decoding code. Something like this "just works":

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let number: Double
}
```

However, the moment something imperfect happens, I need to implement the ENTIRE `CodingKeys` structure as well as the `init(from decoder:)`.

For example, suddenly the API sends back a String as the `number` that I want to represent as an Double, and this requires me to add all this boilerplate.

```
// boilerplate CodingKeys
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case id, name, number
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  // default boilerplate values
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
  name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
  
  // Custom values
  let numberString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .number)
  number = Double(numberString) ?? 0
}
```

This is annoying for a few reasons:

1. One custom item makes me add all this extra code
2. I can't at a glance see which items are actually "custom" and which are just boilerplate (unless I organize my code in that way of course)

I'm just confused as to why it was built this way. Are there technical limitations that require the use of this boilerplate?

And of course is there a way to avoid some of this boilerplate? One solution I saw was to create a different variable like `numberDouble` that could use the string number, but this screws up the naming a bit.

Comment: The compiler auto-synthesizes conformance to Codable, but as soon as you do something manual, it bails. Hard to know why, but my guess is that any manual operation increases complexity for the compiler to cover all the cases in the way that doesn't break what the programmer intended

Comment: What's the actual question? This situation has been discussed here many times, including explanations from the people who write / maintain Codable at Apple. It's just the way the autosynthesis currently works. It's an all or nothing situation. And yes, it's because of technical limitations; doing it the way you imagine, while obviously desirable, is just too difficult at the moment.

Comment: On the other hand, for the simple situation where you receive a String that you'd like to see as a Double, that doesn't require a custom `init`, as the existing answer points out. So if _that_ is the question, then the answer is a good answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your issue using a computed property.

Just make a “fake” variable to hold your string and use a custom CodingKey to decode it. Then use a computed property that coverts the “fake” variable to a Double.

Still some additional lines of code but less complicated that writing a custom decoder.

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    private let numberString: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case numberString = "number"
    }
    
    var number: Double {
        Double(numberString) ?? 0
    }
    
}

let json = """
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Mike",
  "number":"12"
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode(Foo.self, from: json)
print(result.number)
```

Comment: Yeah this is one way to avoid the `init(decoder:`, but if there are more complex customizations I would eventually have to implement that unless I was ok with that being computed every time I read the property.

Comment: I know, that’s the unfortunate thing, it would be nice if it could synthesize more but it unfortunately doesn’t. For simple cases a computed property is your best bet. For the more complicated - a custom decoder is what you have to go with and all the boilerplate that comes with it. There is a third option, and that is to get your data sent to you in the correct format, but that is not always possible.